# Restart a node process from within itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, fork

Is it possible to restart a running single-threaded node process entirely from within itself?

I imagine the steps to take for a server would be something like this:

- Close the listening sockets
- Fork off a child through either `child_process.fork`or `child_process.spawn`, handing over process.argv to the child.
- process.exit() on the parent (Should not kill the child)
- Child binds the listening sockets again

Could this work or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but generally people just use existing solutions that start a single master process and N server processes. Then when a server process dies or stops, it just starts a new one. One example is [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pm2).

That said, your example sounds correct to me as long as you use the `detached: true` argument for `.spawn`

Comment: Indeed [it works](https://gist.github.com/silverwind/d0802f7a919ae86ff25e)! There's a minor issue of being thrown back at the terminal thought.

Comment: I wonder of it's possible avoid this disconnection from the terminal thought. I inherit stdin, stdout and stderr in above gist, still something about the child process make it lose the forground property of the process.

Comment: @silverwind I don't think that will work because when the parent dies, stdio streams will be disconnected. Using a parent process the constantly respawn children should work though since the parent would never close.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll go the route of having a master process to spawn children. There are apparently ways from C to reattach to a background process, but that stuff is definately not exposed to node.